# how to get the x:name in datatemplate

Tags: uwp

I'm setting the grid in the datatemplate.And i need to add some ellipse in this grid by code,because the amount of ellipse is dynamic setting the grid in the datatemplate.
I also try to add grid and ellipse by code,and add to the datatemplate,but i can't find the visualtree

```
<syncfusion:LineSeries.TooltipTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate  x:Name="pupmadata">
                                    <Border x:Name="PumpAtooltip" Height="72"  BorderBrush="#ff00ffff" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" Background="#FF0B0F3C">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Grid  x:Name="pu">
                                            </Grid>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </syncfusion:LineSeries.TooltipTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DataTemplate` is just a template. It needs to be applied to some element for any element that is defined in the template to be created. Before this, there are is `Border`, `StackPanel` or `Grid` to get a reference to.

If you want to add elements to the `Grid` dynamically, you could handle its `Loaded` event:

```
<Grid  x:Name="pu" Loaded="GridLoaded" />
```

---

```
private void GridLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid pu = (Grid)sender;
    //...
}
```

Comment: thank you ! it work! but i still want to know ,it can't findname in the datatemplate why?